# Are unreadable error messages form CGAL or cppyy?

Tags: c++, cgal, cppyy

I have trying to wrap a small part of CGAL (Computational Geometry
Algorithms Library) using cppyy.  I get completely unreadable error messages.  Are these messages just being passed through from CGAL?

Here is one of the messages.  I have chopped the long lines up into pieces:

Which I have deleted.  Some research revealed that these un-readable
error messages are a well-known problem which gcc and clang are working on.

Here is a survey paper:

```
Compiler Error Messages Considered Unhelpful: The Landscape of Text-Based Programming Error Message Research
  Brett A. Becker, Paul Denny, Raymond Pettit, Durell Bouchard,
  Dennis J. Bouvier, Brian Harrington, Amir Kamil, Amey Karkare,
  Chris McDonald, Peter-Michael Osera, Janice L. Pearce,
  James Prather
ITiCSE-WGR '19: Proceedings of the Working Group Reports on
Innovation and Technology in Computer Science Education,
December, 2019; Pages 177–210;
https://doi.org/10.1145/3344429.3372508
```

Comment: *"I have chopped the long lines up into pieces:"* -- yes you did, and by doing so you made the message less readable, in my view. Better would have been to leave the lines as-is and format the message as a code block (language `none` if you know how to do that).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only asking what the message means ...

`overlap` is apparently a templated function. You're calling it from Python using `cgal.CGAL.overlay(ar0, ar1, big, FOLT)`. Thus, `cppyy` tries to match the argument types (`ar0` etc.) to instantiate that `overlap` function. That is what fails and the reported messages are the instantiations that were tried.

Yes, C++ template error messages are rather ugly/indecipherable. Is the nature of the beast.

Aside, note that if CGAL is using expression templates, then these have a tendency to grow more in Python than they do in C++ b/c assignments in C++ force them to collapse, whereas assignments in Python are by reference. If you want the same type collapse in Python, use an explicit constructor or `__assign__`. (Alternatively, you can use type reducers to force the collapse before returning to Python, but that only works if the use of the expression templates is very systematic. Use of a constructor allows more detailed control otherwise.)